# Improving matrix operations time using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-multiprocessing

Having a 2d numpy array, I'm doing the following operation:

```
rows_count = matrix.shape[0]
mr = []
for i in range(0, rows_count-1):
    for j in range(i+1, rows_count):
        mr.append(matrix[i,:] ^ matrix[j:])
```

It's doing exactly what I want, but it is too slow for big input arrays. That's why I wanted to use `multiprocessing` to speed up my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
mr = pool.map(np.bitwise_xor,[(matrix[i,:],matrix[j,:]) for i in range(0, rows_count-1) for j in range(i+1, rows_count)])
pool.join()
pool.close()
```

However, this code works couple times slower. How can I correctly use `multiprocessing` (or other concept) to speed up my code?

Comment: Check out Joblib, which makes it easy to [share Numpy arrays across processes by memory-mapping](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html#working-with-numerical-data-in-shared-memory-memmapping).

Answer (score 0):

checkout numba!

your new code would look like this

```
from numba import jit

@jit(parallel=True) #yes this decorator and flag is all it takes to run the function in parallel
def my_time_cosuming_thing(mr=[],matrix=np.array(), rows_count=matrix.shape[0])

    for i in range(0, rows_count-1):
      for j in range(i+1, rows_count):
        mr.append(matrix[i,:] ^ matrix[j:])

    return mr
```

Numba was created to make python loops super efficient by attempting to make them run in parallel, check it out at http://numba.pydata.org/

It's also compatible with numpy so this should significantly speed up your code, it's like magic and works so well i never write nested loops without it anymore

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution also seems to be slower than simple for loop.

Comment: that's weird, sorry for what could seem like a plug but [here](https://github.com/vencaslac/grav_sim2/blob/master/utils.py) is one project where i've implemented this and it simply would not work at all without numba, maybe try replicating that? you can try to comment out the @jit lines and see it grind to a halt